# What's the mean of 'a sample of' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> A chemical property is the ability (or inability) of a sample of matter to undergo a change in composition under stated conditions.

What's the mean of 'a sample of' in this sentence? Does it means 'one kind of' or something else?

Comment: Please tell us about the dictionary definitions you found and why you dismissed each of them as not a possibility in this context.

Comment: There is only one definition in my dictionary, it's something for analysis. So I want to confirm what's the mean of this phrase. Am I asked wrong question？if i asked wrong question, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but to say it better it is:

- A small part from a larger whole, showing the quality, style, or nature of the whole
- Specimen

http://www.wordreference.com/definition/sample